# Angular 2 loading local json file 403 forbidden error

Tags: angularjs, json, http, servicestack

Seems so simple from examples I see on the web but when I try to load a local json file from my Angular 2 application inside my service.ts, I get a 403 forbidden error.  My application runs inside a Servicestack selfhosted service.  Works fine when I do a request like http://localhost:8087/customers/ but the same data inside a local json file in my app directory will not (http://localhost:8087/app/customers.json)

What do I have to do to allow my application to access that file?

```
this._http.get('app/customers.json').toPromise()
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
        }).catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Perhaps this is due to the fact you're missing `/` in your `GET` call?

Comment: It looks like it's a conflict, ServiceStack let's you add a extension to specify which format should be returned. What does your Route definition look like?

Comment: @mythz Thank you.  adding HostConfig.Instance.AllowFileExtensions.Add("json"); fixed it.  You rock mythz!

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion from @mythz fixed my issue.
I added this line in my appHost file.

```
HostConfig.Instance.AllowFileExtensions.Add("json");
```